# Is it possible to easily debug an iPhone serial-port app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, serial-port, jailbreak

I'm now trying to connect my iPod Touch(iOS4 jailbroken) with Ecomote(a small embedded system) through serial port. I just followed this instruction: http://hcgilje.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/iphone-serial-communication/.

All things going well except that I need to move my application to /Application/MyApp.app and chmod it to 777. However, it is hard to debug because I can't use Xcode to run the app directly. Is it possible to debug with Xcode? Or how can I link to an additional console to show the NSLog/printf message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the syslog package in Cydia to enable syslog, then use `tail -f /var/log/syslog` from an SSH shell to catch `NSLog`/`printf` statements.

Comment: I don't think the `print` statements show up in the /var/log/syslog